# Swift 2.0 String to Integer

Tags: ios, swift2, beta

So I've been trying to convert this string of input numbers into variables but for some reason, every possible combination I try, it always gives me an error

```
@IBOutlet weak var age: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var finalYears: UILabel!
@IBAction func findYears(sender: AnyObject) {

    var enteredYears = age.text.toInt()
    if enteredYears != nil {
        var catYears = enteredYears * 7
        finalYears.text = "Your cat is \(catYears)"
    } else {
        finalYears.text = "Please enter another number"
    }
}
```

And for some reason on the line

```
var enteredYears = age.text.toInt()
```

I always seem to get an error that conflicts with every other line after that piece of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 2 you have to use the `Int` initializer instead of `.toInt()` (returns `Int?`):

```
var enteredYears = Int(age.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

toInt() returns an optional Int?, since it is possible for the String to Int conversion to fail.